# Backbone render the view once the dom loaded to avoid div jumping

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

Adding the view to dom id main-wrapper one router calls the view.Page loads one by one because of the sub view added in within main-wrapper. Need to know something similar to smooth loading the dom with fade in effect or shows the page once the dom is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach you can take is hold off on adding the view to the main-wrapper until all subviews are created. Create a document fragment (default behavior if "el" is not defined). Once your view and its descendent views are all created in document fragment, then add it to the main-wrapper div. This way all of your content are shown at the same time instead of one view at a time.

Comment: nice one. That is exactly I thought but would be good and helpful if any example to check whether sub view created or not.

Answer (score 0):

Either use jQuery's onReady event or the native window.onload event. In both cases you register a callback function that then kicks of the initialization of the respective Backbone views.